# Selenium - unable to discover open window in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

I am trying to run a test using chrome, but when the browser launches the test fails and I see the below error.

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unable to
>   discover open window in chrome

I am using the most recent versions of selenium and chrome driver

- Webdriver - 2.46
- Chrome driver - 2.16
- Chrome browser - 43

This error only occurs when running the tests on my local machine. If I run these tests on a grid VM, chrome will open without any issues and the test will run. The grid VM and my local machine have the exact same versions of chrome, chrome driver, and webdriver.

What can I look for on my local machine to resolve the issue? I've tried to reinstall chrome, but that didn't help. 
[image]